# *ngIf blocking interaction with button

Tags: angular, roles

I am trying to develop an app with authorization and roles, so I am trying to hide and show stuff with the help of ngIf.

The problem is, when I put the condition ngIf to hide one component of my navebar the login stops working, using the debugger the function that the click triggers is not even called.

The site makes refresh, passing from localhost1234/login to localhost1234/login?, what can possibly be?

I can't understand why, can anyone help?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-juswfc

Link with the files involved.

Thank you !

Comment: Hello, the stackblitz project doesn't work, `/src/index.html` and `/src/main.ts` are missing, probably also other parts of the project, I assume it is just copy paste from your project and not meant to work

Comment: Yes, I put it on stackblitz because it was to big to copy past in stackoverflow.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could replicate your issue in that project, that would make the problem a lot easier to identify

Comment: I can't, because when you click Login it makes a call to NodeJs to check for the user.

But the problem is the follow: 
When I am have a *ngIf in line 22 of app.component.html the login button can't call the submit method.
When I dont have the *ngIf works completly fine.